# When Must the Rate of Convergence be Worse on the Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

WLOG, let $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disc with radius of convergence $1$ around $z=0$. My question is about a sense in which we can say that the rate of convergence of the taylor expansion of $f$ around $0$ must be *worse* everywhere on the boundary of the disc of convergence than in the interior.

If we define $$E_n(z) = \left|f(z) - \sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k\right|$$ to be the error resulting from the $n$-term truncation of the Taylor series. Then more specifically, the question can be stated as follows:

Given some $z_1$ in the interior of the unit disc, and some $z_2$ on the boundary, and perhaps some conditions on $f$, do we know that for all sufficiently large $n$, $E_n(z_1) \leq E_n(z_2)$?

I believe that this holds automatically if the Taylor series of $f$ diverges at $z_2$, but either way the interesting case seems to me to be the one where the Taylor series converges at $z_2$, so that can be assumed if you like.

By Cauchy-Hadamard, we can know that for all $z$ in the interior of the unit disc (with $ 0<|z|=r < 1$), we have that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_nz^n|^{1/n} \leq r < 1 $$ and that we can not obviously say that about the boundary. But it seems a lot less trivial to show lower bounds on the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited from previous answer.**

Counterexample: Define

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}-z^{2k+1}}{(k+1)^2}.$$

The radius of convergence of this power series is $1.$ Let $z_1=-1/2, z_2=1.$ Then $E_n(-1/2)>0$ for all $n$ and $E_n(1)=0$ for all odd $n.$

If we don't insist on a finite radius of convergence, we can use my previous answer:

$$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k}-z^{2k+1}}{k!}.$$

This $f$ is entire. Again let $z_1=-1/2, z_2=1$ to see $E_n(-1/2)>0$ for all $n$ and $E_n(1)=0$ for all odd $n.$

Comment: If I understand this, this isn't a full counterexample since t $z_2$ isn't on the boundary of the disc of convergence. That said, I suspect this is all but a full solution. It's at least enough to convince me that the answer to the question asked is probably no.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (E_n(z_1) -E_n(z_2)$ can be made negative, as well. Clearly the $\liminf$ analog can be, and presumably can be with a slight variation on this theme in the case that $z_2$ is on the boundary of the disc of convergence.

Comment: I forgot that $z_2$ was supposed to be on the unit circle, with the radius of convergence of the power series $=1.$ Nicely enough, it's easy to define a counterexample that satisfies this. See my new answer above.

Comment: On your second comment: If the power series of $f$ converges at $z_2,$ then both $E_n(z_1), E_n(z_2)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Hence $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are both $0.$

Comment: Ah, clear on both points. That clears up the question nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can show that the quantity $|f(z) - P_n(z)|$ attains its maximum on the boundary of the disk, where $P_n(z) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n a_n z^k$.

This follows immediately from the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: This is useful, but what I meant to ask is whether it must be the case that the rate of convergence of any point on the boundary must be worse than that of any point in the interior. Perhaps I should edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @CadeReinberger: Why do you expect the Taylor series to converge at boundary points at all? Is this an assumption you're making?

Comment: Well, if the Taylor series diverges at $z_2$, then it would seem like the question would certainly be answered in the affirmative in that case, since the $n$-term error at $z_2$ doesn't get arbitrarily small, but that happens at $z_1$.

Comment: The series may converge at every point on the boundary of the disk without $f$ being analytic at every point on the boundary. E.g. $f(x)=x+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-x)^n/(n^2-n).$ For $|x|<1$ and for  $(-1\ne 0\land |x|=1)$ this is the principal branch of $(1+x)\log (1+x).$  Note the essential singularity in $f'(x)$ at $x=-1.$

Comment: If the series diverges at $z_2$ then what does $f(z_2)$ even mean?

Comment: Indeed, the error $E_n(z_2)$ isn't meaningfully defined when the series diverges there. Roughly speaking, one may imagine the error as being infinite as a sort of definition, so the result roughly holds in that case, but regardless that case isn't the interesting one.